# Updating UI from a background thread in ScalaFX

Tags: multithreading, scala, scalafx

Here is the code:

```
import javafx.event
import javafx.event.EventHandler

import scalafx.application.{Platform, JFXApp}
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.event.ActionEvent
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.{Button, Label}
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.scene.layout.{VBox, HBox}

object Blocking extends JFXApp {
  val statusLbl = new Label("Not started...")
  val startBtn = new Button("Start") {
    onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => startTask
  }
  val exitBtn = new Button("Exit") {
    onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => stage.close()
  }
  val buttonBox = new HBox(5, startBtn, exitBtn)
  val vBox = new VBox(10, statusLbl, buttonBox)

  def startTask = {
    val backgroundThread = new Thread {
      setDaemon(true)
      override def run = {
        runTask
      }
    }
    backgroundThread.start()
  }

  def runTask = {
    for(i <- 1 to 10) {
      try {
        val status =  "Processing " + i + " of " + 10
        Platform.runLater(() => {
          statusLbl.text = status
        })
        println(status)
        Thread.sleep(1000)
      } catch {
        case e: InterruptedException => e.printStackTrace()
      }
    }
  }

  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    title = "Blocking"
    scene = new Scene {
      root = vBox
    }
  }
}
```

When the "start" button is pressed, the status label should be updated 10 times, but it is not. From the console you can see the background thread is actually updating the status, but these are not reflected in the UI. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the invocation of `Platform.runLater`. To make it work change it to:

```
Platform.runLater {
  statusLbl.text = status
}
```

`runLater[R](op: => R)` takes as an argument a code block that returns a value of type `R`. You were passing a code block defining an anonymous function. `runLater` was creating a function, not executing it.